# Time Complexity of Recurrence Relation: T(n) = nT(n^1/2)+ O(1)

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

I want to solve this Recurrence Relation using telescoping: `T(n) = nT( n^(1/2) )+ O(1)`. But, I get stucked at the final steps. I checked all posts, there is no similar problems.

I've tried:
[image]

I have listed substems and generalized it. I am not about the next step, can I get some help?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Above you write nT(n^2), but the image shows nT(sqrt(n)).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a mathematics question, not a computer programming question.

Comment: @Thomas Mueller Thanks for pointing out. FIxed the typo.

Comment: @kevin Best to post here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `n = 2^(2^m)`, we have `√n = 2^(2^(m-1))`. The recurrence writes

```
U(m) = 2^(2^m).U(m-1) + O(1).
```

The homogenous equation has the solution

```
U(m) = 2^(2^m).2^(2^(m-1)).… 2^(2^1).U(0) 
     = 2^(2^m+2^(m-1)+ … 2).U(0)
     = 2^(2^(m+1)-2).U(0)
```

or

```
T(n) = n²/4.T(2)
```

If I am right, we can add a low-order term,

```
T(n) = n²/4.T(2) + O(1/n²),
```

as

```
n(√n²/4.T(2) + O(1/√n²)) = n²/4.T(2) + O(1).
```

Comment: Why we assume n=2^(2^m)?

Comment: What do you mean by .T(2)?  What does the dot mean? Thanks

Comment: @kevin: the dot is the product operator.